# scikit-image pixel by pixel manipulation

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-image

I need to read an image and then perform a function on each pixel, and then save it as a new image. I use scikit-image for the first and last part (reading and writing) but I'm having trouble doing the second operation (the actual conversion) in a fast way.

The result of the read operation in scikit-image is a numpy array of the shape (WIDTH, HEIGHT, N_CHANNELS) where WIDTH and HEIGHT is of the image and N_CHANNELS is either 3 or 4. I need to apply a function such as one that converts the pixel from [R, G, B] to [R - B, G - B, B - R] to each pixel individually.

I've spend a few days trying to get this working, but the only working solution that I have so far is to loop over each row and column and perform the calculation. This takes an extremely long time to complete.

I've tried to vectorize the array but the result is a 1D array and it isn't possible to work with that. Is there any other performant way to get this done?

```
def calculate_ndvi(nir, red):
    if red == 0 and nir == 0:
        return 0.5
    else:
        num = int(nir) - int(red)
        den = int(nir) + int(red)
        return num / den


zero_uint = numpy.uint8(0)


def process_color(clr):
    ndvi = calculate_ndvi(clr[2], clr[0])
    return [-ndvi, ndvi, zero_uint]


def save_ndvi_file():
    image = io.imread(input_path)

    rows = image.shape[0]
    cols = image.shape[1]

    out = numpy.empty(shape=(rows, cols, 3))
    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            out[i][j] = process_color(image[i][j])

    io.imsave('output.jpg', out)
```

Comment: Without seeing your code, the best we can do is guess. Please prepare a [mcve]. It shouldn't take very long to apply that function on a 25MP file, so you're probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You can vectorize this by using multi-dimensional broadcasting of operations. Here is a version of your function that does everything in a vectorized manner:

```
def save_ndvi_file():
    image = io.imread(input_path)

    nir = image[:, :, 2]
    red = image[:, :, 0]
    ndvi = (nir - red) / (nir + red)
    ndvi[(nir == 0) & (red == 0)] = 0.5
    out = ndvi[:, :, np.newaxis] * np.array([[[-1, 1, 0]]])

    io.imsave('output.jpg', out)
```

Notice that all the things you had looped over are now done via broadcasted numpy operations, rather than by looping over external function calls. Writing code this way requires a slightly different way of thinking about the algorithm, but it is quite intuitive once you're used to it.